# How to implement PT_DENY_ATTACH (anti-debugging in iOS )

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst

PT_DENY_ATTACH is an anti-debugging feature that helps prevent debuggers from attaching to the app. Following code can be implemented in main() to prevent GDB from attaching to the application. :

```
#import <dlfcn.h>
#import <sys/types.h>
typedef int (*ptrace_ptr_t)(int _request, pid_t _pid, caddr_t _addr, int _data);
#define PT_DENY_ATTACH 31
void disable_gdb() {
void* handle = dlopen(0, RTLD_GLOBAL | RTLD_NOW);
ptrace_ptr_t ptrace_ptr = dlsym(handle, "ptrace");
ptrace_ptr(PT_DENY_ATTACH, 0, 0, 0);
dlclose(handle);
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
@autoreleasepool {
#ifdef DEBUG
//do nothing
#else
disable_gdb();
#endif
}}
```

Answer (score 3):

Guys it is true that this trick has been worked around and can be bypassed by overriding but have a look at [that](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Crack_prevention#PT_DENY_ATTACH)

Here the guys from iphonedevwiki.net are showing another way to implement the same thing in assembly, making it much harder to be patched. So to bypass this assembly implementation one has to have the Mach-O binary decrypted and override the implementation of the function, for example an attacker could swap all assembly instructions from the function with only `nop` instructions which do nothing. But if you obfuscate your assembly routine, it will be much harder for attacker to recognise what is happening, so only the most experienced folks will be able bypass that.

For those of you who don't know how to write assembly in Swift 5 project, here is what you will need to do:

1. Create a new `C` File + Header
2. lets name them `disable_debuggers_advanced.c` and `disable_debuggers_advanced.h`
3. In `disable_debuggers_advanced.c` add the following:

```c
#include "disable_debug_advanced.h"

void mRiYXNnZnZmZGF2Ym() {

    // No Need to encode these strings, because they will be directly compiled, they are not going to be present in the 'DATA' segment of the binary.
    __asm (
           "mov r0, #31\n" // set #define PT_DENY_ATTACH (31) to r0
           "mov r1, #0\n"   // clear r1
           "mov r2, #0\n"   // clear r2
           "mov r3, #0\n"   // clear r3
           "mov ip, #26\n"  // set the instruction pointer to syscal 26
           "svc #0x80\n"    // SVC (formerly SWI) generates a supervisor call. Supervisor calls are normally used to request privileged operations or access to system resources from an operating system
           );
}
```

4. In `disable_debuggers_advanced.h` add the following:

```c
#ifndef disable_debug_advanced_h
#define disable_debug_advanced_h

#include <stdio.h>


/**
 Original name: `disable_gdb_advanced()`

 This function makes the process deny the attaching request by debugers by
 simulating what is already available on macOS:

 ptrace(PT_DENY_ATTACH, 0, 0, 0);

 by implementing it directly in assembly language.

 This method of disabling debugers is well known to attackers but there is nothing they can do to easily bypass it
 because it is a part of the kernel memory space.

 Please note that this will make XCode not being able to attach its debuger to the process too,
 so run it only in release builds.

 source: https://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Crack_prevention#PT_DENY_ATTACH
 */
void mRiYXNnZnZmZGF2Ym(void) __attribute__((always_inline));

#endif /* disable_debug_advanced_h */
```

5. Add `#include "disable_debug_advanced.h"` to your bridging header and a bridging header if your project does not already have one.

Now you can call this function to disable debuggers.

*Note that this will break even the XCode debugger, so use it only on release builds*

If you are wondering about the `__attribute__((always_inline))` part and the weird name it is because we want our function to be hidden as much as possible. If you are not familiar with function inlining, you can watch my video about function inlining [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YbfK74lhj0g) where i describe it in depth or you can read in [wikipedia about it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_function). Even thought it is a speed compiler optimisation, it could give us benefits here because if you call it from multiple locations it will be harder for attacker to patch all function body copies in the app.

And the name is written like this, because this **inlining is just a hint to the compiler, it is not guaranteed that it will happen**. And if it does not happen and our function for disabling the debugger is clearly defined in the TEXT segment of our binary, we want it to be at least with obfuscated name, so that no one could guess what it does just by reading its assembly label.

In my opinion one should call this as a top level function even before the `UIApplication` object is created.

In order to do that:

1. Add a new file to your Swift project and **name it 'main.swift' (NAME IS IMPORTANT)**
2. Remove the @UIApplicationMain tag from your `AppDelegate`s  class definition.
3. In your `main.swift` file write the following:

```swift
mRiYXNnZnZmZGF2Ym() // disable debuggers

// initialises the UIApplication and fires the event loop.
// This function never returns!
UIApplicationMain(CommandLine.argc, CommandLine.unsafeArgv, nil, NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate.self))
```

If you want to see a video of how to execute top level code in `main.swift`, you can see me doing it on [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kt5N2DGWPxI)

In attempt to make it even more obfuscated and harder to crack, one could use assembly obfuscators like [this one Movfuscator](https://github.com/xoreaxeaxeax/movfuscator) so that only a few people would be able to recognise what these assembly instructions mean.

Comment: __asm (
           "mov r0, #31\n" // set #define PT_DENY_ATTACH (31) to r0
           );

For this i am getting Unknown token in expression erro. How it can be solved?

Comment: I'm getting `Invalid operand for instruction` error on every `mov` "mov r0, #31\n", etc...

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** according to the wiki page of this tool, it has been workearound and must not be used:

> IMPORTANT NOTE: This trick has been worked around by pirates. Don't rely on it!

Assuming you are referring to a Hybrid application created in MobileFirst Studio 7.1 - this, well, is not different than any other iOS app.

The end result of a Hybrid app, is still an Xcode project that you open in Xcode in order to build the application. This means then that you need to place your code in the same place in the Xcode project as if this was a regular Xcode project (which, it is), per the [wiki page for PT_DENY_ATTACH](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Bugging_Debuggers).

Comment: Thanks Idan for quick reply. But we are unable to find int main() function in the Xcode project generated by Mobilefirst. Can you please help ?

Comment: I don't see why you are still pursuing this when the team behind the workaround declared it unsafe to use. You are not adding any protection to your project by using this.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by @Idan Adar - this trick is workedAround, but in case u want to try it in any education or some other purpose u can try do following:

1. add define for u'r app to allow u run and debug if needed

   ```
   #define SOME
   ```
2. add following code in main.m

   ```
   #define SOME

   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
   #import "AppDelegate.h"

   #ifdef SOME

   #import <dlfcn.h>
   #import <sys/types.h>

    typedef int (*ptrace_ptr_t)(int request, pid_t pid, caddr_t addr, int data);
   #if !defined(PT_DENY_ATTACH)
   #define PT_DENY_ATTACH 31
   #endif  // !defined(PT_DENY_ATTACH)

    void disable_gdb();

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
   //   disable_gdb();
   @autoreleasepool {
             return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
   }
   }

    void disable_gdb()
   {
             void* handle = dlopen(0, RTLD_GLOBAL | RTLD_NOW);
             ptrace_ptr_t ptrace_ptr = dlsym(handle, "ptrace");
             ptrace_ptr(PT_DENY_ATTACH, 0, 0, 0);
             dlclose(handle);
   }

    int main3(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
             return -1;
   }

   #else

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
   @autoreleasepool {
             return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
     }
   }

   #endif
   ```

[Here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/45645/ios-app-security-analysis-part-1) - some good points to start about

Answer (score 0):

I saw this question has not marked correct answered yet. I already use below code block to use anti-debugging. Please open your main.m file to added below code snipped.

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "Application.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef int (*PYStdWriter)(void *, const char *, int);
static PYStdWriter _oldStdWrite;
#define   PT_DENY_ATTACH  31

int __pyStderrWrite(void *inFD, const char *buffer, int size)
{
    if ( strncmp(buffer, "AssertMacros:", 13) == 0 ) {
        return 0;
    }
    return _oldStdWrite(inFD, buffer, size);
}

static int is_debugger_present(void)
{
    int name[4];
    struct kinfo_proc info;
    size_t info_size = sizeof(info);

    info.kp_proc.p_flag = 0;

    name[0] = CTL_KERN;
    name[1] = KERN_PROC;
    name[2] = KERN_PROC_PID;
    name[3] = getpid();

    if (sysctl(name, 4, &info, &info_size, NULL, 0) == -1) {
        perror("sysctl");
        exit(-1);
    }
    return ((info.kp_proc.p_flag & P_TRACED) != 0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {


#ifdef DEBUG
    _oldStdWrite = stderr->_write;
    stderr->_write = __pyStderrWrite;
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, NSStringFromClass([Application class]), NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
#else
    //Anti Debugging Code
    //https://coredump.gr/articles/ios-anti-debugging-protections-part-2/

    //ptrace(PT_DENY_ATTACH, 0, 0, 0);
    printf("Looping forever");
    fflush(stdout);
    while (1)
    {
        sleep(1);
        if (is_debugger_present())
        {
            //[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"isAntiDebug"];
            printf("Debugger detected! Terminating...\n");
            return -1;
        }
        printf(".");
        fflush(stdout);

        _oldStdWrite = stderr->_write;
        stderr->_write = __pyStderrWrite;
        @autoreleasepool {
            //[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"isAntiDebug"];
            int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, NSStringFromClass([Application class]), NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
            return retVal;
        }
    }

#endif
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how to and where to implement this in swift?

Comment: Hi @VijayKharage, you can not implement "anti-debugging" for swift.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by [Stoyan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55575155/13760129). Your implementation could be easily bypassed. You should add an assembly code. Just one missing thing from the above answer is that you have to add `arm64` macro or you will not be able to build your project on simulators (OS X are using x86_64 arch)

So add this:

```
#if defined (__arm64__)
    __asm(
        "mov x0, #26\n" // ptrace
        "mov x1, #31\n" // PT_DENY_ATTACH
        "mov x2, #0\n"
        "mov x3, #0\n"
        "mov x16, #0\n"
        "svc #128\n"
    );
```

I wrote a simple [guide](https://www.iamin.dev/ios%20security/iOS-security-ptrace-deny-attach/) for this. Check it out

Comment: I think this is wrong.  I believe x16 contains the system call number.

Comment: @Myria "This method is equivalent to using syscall(SYS_ptrace, PT_DENY_ATTACH, 0, 0, 0). It should be noted here that the system call number at this time is 0, that is SYS_syscall"